Editing control by Roles in WFS in QGIS
How can I make layer-level editing settings in GeoServer in the WFS service? I want to limit access to layered editing to a selective group (Role editor), only for this Role. In this case, editing via WFS in QGIS.

did you try looking in the manual - https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/layer.html#security-layer

Another user answered me, basically, I wanted to know the following: "wfs.* grants read access via WFS; wfs.Transaction grants the editor access only to users who have this role". And it is available at https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/service.html
And thank you for your time.
